# Invoke-RestMethod Link Method not supported

Tags: powershell

I'm interfacing with an API with PowerShell `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet.
One of the API endpoints requires the method "Link", however this method is not supported by `Invoke-RestMethod`.

With CURL it is working fine

Is there a way around this?

Error message:

> Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot bind parameter 'Method'. Cannot convert value "LINK" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestMethod". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name LINK to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
>   Default, Get, Head, Post, Put, Delete, Trace, Options, Merge, Patch

Comment: did you try `-CustomMethod` in `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell v6+, `Invoke-WebRequest` has a parameter `CustomMethod`.

> This can be used with the Request Method required by the endpoint is not an available option on the -Method.

Look at the MS documentation on [how to use custom method in invoke-webrequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)

**Update**

You can use .Net class `WebRequest` to send your request as follows, and this will work on any PowerShell version:

```
$req = [net.webrequest]::create('https://www.google.com')
$req.Method = 'LINK'
$resp = $req.GetResponse()
```

Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8) for further information

Comment: Worth noting it PS 6+ only

Comment: Yes, noticed that as well. That is an issue for me as not all our servers have this PS version

Comment: Ohh sorry, i didn't notice that.

Comment: Thx! I have it working with the .Net class, but I might explore the PS v6 route  as well, need to do that anyway at some point I guess